# Excel VBA-error saving file without macros

Tags: excel, vba

Have had this code running for months, all the sudden I am getting this error message, not sure if there was an update or what happened.

> Run-Time error '1004: VB Projects and XLM Sheets cannot be save in a
> macro-free workbook.

Code is to save the workbook without macros so that it can be e-mailed to end users without macros. Has been working every day for months without an issue.

```
strFile = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\BorstDailyKPI" & ".xlsx" 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: Nothing has changed, worked last night, not tonight.   Unless there was an excel update.  Same workbook, same macro.   Added Strfile info in original post

Comment: Does the file now have a macro? Save as `.xlsm`?  Also why are you concatenating the path? `BorstDailyKPI.xlsm` may work.

Comment: There is definitely no excel update that would have caused this to stop working. If your workbook contains a macro, this error would have always come up by default. It could have been bypassed by `Application.DisplayAlerts` set to `False`, which is now being left `True`. Did you get the "The following features cannot be saved in macro-free workbooks" popup before the VBA error? And were you getting that popup previously?

Comment: If you have `Option Explicit` on by default then just checking to see if there is a macro present will create one. You need to actively delete it.

Comment: Depends how you check @user10186832 . If you just go to VBA with ALT+F11, then you won't create anything by checking if it has something.

Comment: This macro is in the workbook and always has been and always worked.  Been a while since I originally wrote it, but thinking the reason the displayalerts was in there was to get around a message that warned of this when I originally wrote it.   See others below are recently seeing the same issue.

Comment: Getting a message when doing the process manually that I have never seen before.  Says: The following features cannot be saved in macro free workbooks  *VP project  To Save this workbook with these features and turn autosave off, select Save.  to save with autosave on, you can either save and manually restart excel and the features will be lost on restart or select save and erase features.  If you would like to save your features with autosave on, go back and change the file type to a macro-enabled file type (.xlsm).

Comment: Some users here have the same problem with Version 2311. Strangely enough, others (and I) are also on 2311 and don't get the error. -- See also here for workaround ideas: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vb-projects-and-xlm-sheets-cannot-be-saved-in-a-macro-free-workbook.1250137/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I think it is a bug in Excel introduced by update from 29 November. Downgrading to version 2310 (Build 16924.20150) from 14 November fixed it.

Instruction how to downgrade: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2bd5c457-a917-d57e-35a1-f709e3dda841

Release history: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fae942449-1fca-4484-898b-a933ea23def7

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation at exactly the same time. I uninstalled Microsoft 365, rebooted, and reinstalled the old Excel 2016 with the offline installer and got around the 1004 with the same xlsm with same VBS code. However, this is only a temporary fix...

Comment: Version 2311 (Build 17029.20068) > Resolved issues > Excel
> We fixed an issue where the Save dialog wouldn't always save or would get stuck when closing a local file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/current-channel#excel

This change appears to be the cause of this glitch.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same situation since some days ago. I used, for years, the `SaveAs` command preceded by the following instructions (and reset them after the `SaveAs` command):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.PrintCommunication = False
```

Something was changed in Excel/VBA.

Answer (score 0):

First copy the sheets in the Workbook section by:

**Me.Sheets.Copy**

and after that, use:

**ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=[FilePath], FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook**

(after **Me.Sheets.Copy** the (so new initiated) ActiveWorkbook only contains a copy of the sheets without any code)

Code in the **Workbook_BeforeSave** event looks like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  
  If Me.FileFormat = XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled Or Me.FileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook Then Exit Sub
  Me.Sheets.Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=[FilePath], FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
  Me.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

After that original Workbook which is represented by "Me" has to be closed by:

**Me.Close SaveChanges:=False**

The original Workbook has vanished and only the saved Version without code stays.

Comment: Sorry, this only works, if there is no code in the sheets section

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete all Code of the Workbook you must make sure that you trust access to the VBA project object model, in **File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings... > Macro Settings**.

Following code deletes all codelines from the Workbook before saving a copy of it as OpenXMLWorkbook.

You also need a reference on
**Microsoft Visual Basic for Application Extensibility 5.3**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  
  If Me.FileFormat = XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled Or Me.FileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook Then Exit Sub
  
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  
  Dim VBC As VBComponent
  Me.Sheets.Copy
  
  For Each VBC In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    With VBC.CodeModule
      .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
    End With
  Next VBC
  
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=[FilePath], FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
  
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  
  Me.Close SaveChanges:=False
  
End Sub
```